# How can I configure azure analysis services privacy settings in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, powerbi, powerquery, azure-analysis-services

I have seen many posts to overcome this error:

" Formula.Firewall: Query 'xxxxxxx' (step 'xxxxxxx') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination. "

The Answer has ALWAYS been:
"" You need to set the privacy settings of your data sources & workbook. See https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Privacy-levels-Power-Query-cc3ede4d-359e-4b28-bc72-9bee7900b540?ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA ""

My problem is: I am using VS to develop my model on AAS.

So the options to configure the security in VS for AAS are differnet - and I cannot find the same options for privacy that exist in Power BI and Excel for tabular model development.

For context: I am trying to create a function that uses Azure Cognitive Services (Translate Text) to translate text from an Azure Data Lake data source, and I am getting this error...

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing a similar issue. Maybe activating fast combine could help with the issue?

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/privacy-levels-power-query-cc3ede4d-359e-4b28-bc72-9bee7900b540?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

You can activate this by looking at the properties of the model.bim file. (data access options > enable fast combine).

Otherwise, another thing that may have worked for us was to set the 
"PrivacySetting": "Organizational" in the credential {} of each data source (directly in the code of the bim file)

Comment: So I enabled "Fast Combine" and it did not solve the issue.

Comment: I will try to edit the .bim file directly as you have mentioned.

Comment: I tried to add the "PrivacySetting": "Organizational" in the .bim file, but it did not work. I was able to open the model, and try my queries, but none of my web service calls are working. I have one to azure cognative services, and four to our internal servers (those are giving this error: " Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'An M partition uses a data function which results in access to a data source different from those defined in the model.'.  "  )

Comment: I can confirm that neither of this works... I'm finding myself with the same error using the most simple example, i.e. looking up data via an external api using a field value as parameter. Think "vlookup".